# How many executors will do the job? Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say we have 1000 input files.
We're doing some processing on the files.

1. We set num executors to 200, and after processing we write the result on disk.
2. We set num executors to 200, and after processing we coalesce(1) the result and write the result on disk.
3. We set num executors to 200, and after processing cache the result, than we coalesce(1) the cached result and write on disk.
4. We set num executors to 200, and after processing persist the result on disk, than we coalesce(1) the persisted result and write on disk.
5. We set num executors to 200, and after processing we repartition(1) the result and write the result on disk.
6. We set num executors to 200, and after processing cache the result, than we repartition(1) the cached result and write on disk.
7. We set num executors to 200, and after processing persist the result on disk, than we repartition(1) the persisted result and write on disk.

**Can anybody explains how much executor will do the job in these cases?**

*My experience is when I tried to collapse the small result files into a single one with coalesce(1) than a single executor did all the processing, even if I cached the result before (that should trigger an action as far as I know). So I did the following "hack". I wrote the multifile result on disk, than read it back coalesce(1) and write it back again.*
Note: I processed multiple TB of data and the result is tiny just a few kb.

I have the feeling that I missed something or not do it right, or because of the coalesce(1) it must be processed by a single executor no matter what? A logical step would be a pyramid merge of the results.

I used Spark 1.6

Comment: did you get any insights out of it? I'm facing the same issue (single executor when performing coalesce(1)) with spark 2.1.1

Comment: Unfortunately no answer. My problem kind of solved with the hack I mention in the question, so I didn't spent more time to dig deeper. But if you figure out something I'm interested to hear it.

Comment: So I got to a conclusion - when running `.repartition()` or `.coalesce()` at the end of transformations chains, it's actually translated to something like `... some query... DISTRIBUTE BY key `. So in fact, the redistribution happens before the transformations, causing the side effect you're witnessing. So instead I would use `.collect()`, create a new RDD from the collected data and then repartition it to a single partition, which is somewhat similar to your solution, but without saving the intermediate files.